# How to use internal memory in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android

I have only been making apps on Android Studio for about 3 months, and I am making an app for Higher or Lower. The point is, I would like to make a toast pop up with the high scores whenever the user presses a button. I know how to make an OnClick function, but I want to show the highest scores the user has ever had since the install of the app, not just since the app has been opened. I need these to be displayed when I press a button called "High Score" Anyone know how to do that? If you need any more info, just ask. I am new to stack overflow.

Here's the activity code:

```
package com.nicorodriguez.yarokshigherorlower;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    int num;

    int guesses = 0;
    int highscore = getSavedHighScore();

    private static final String SAVED_HIGH_SCORE_INT = "high_score";

    private void saveHighScore(int highscore) {
        SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        SharedPreferences.Editor spe = sp.edit();
        spe.putInt(SAVED_HIGH_SCORE_INT, highscore);
        spe.apply();
    }

    private int getSavedHighScore(){
        SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        return sp.getInt(SAVED_HIGH_SCORE_INT, -1);
    }

    public void mouseClicked (View view) {

        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.guess);

        int guessnum = Integer.parseInt(editText.getText().toString());

        if(guessnum > num){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Guess Lower.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            guesses += 1;

        }else if(guessnum < num) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Guess Higher.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            guesses += 1;

        } else {
            Random rand = new Random();
            guesses += 1;
            String guesstring = Integer.toString(guesses);
            String highstring = Integer.toString(highscore);
            Toast.makeText(this, "For your trouble, please try again.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            if(guesses < highscore){
                saveHighScore(guesses);
                Toast.makeText(this, "New High Score! \nScore: " + guesstring, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                if(highscore != 9999999) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "\nPrevious High Score: " + highstring, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                highscore = guesses;
            } else if(guesses == highscore) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Aww... What a shame. You tied the high score! \nScore: " + guesstring, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Score: " + guesstring + "\nHigh Score: " + highstring, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            num = rand.nextInt(1000) + 1;
            int guesses = 0;
        }

        Log.i("Info", Integer.toString(num));
    }

    public void highClick (View view) {
        getSavedHighScore();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Your all-time high score is " + highscore, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Random rand = new Random();
        num = rand.nextInt(1000) + 1;
        getSavedHighScore();

    }
}
```

Here's the Stacktrace Filter: Error It's really long. I hope this is what you want:

```
2020-07-17 11:38:34.040 344-344/? E/Zygote: isWhitelistProcess - Process is Whitelisted
2020-07-17 11:38:34.045 344-344/? E/Zygote: accessInfo : 1
2020-07-17 11:38:34.383 344-344/com.nicorodriguez.yarokshigherorlower E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.nicorodriguez.yarokshigherorlower, PID: 344
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.nicorodriguez.yarokshigherorlower/com.nicorodriguez.yarokshigherorlower.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.SharedPreferences android.content.Context.getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String, int)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3042)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3282)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1970)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7156)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:975)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.SharedPreferences android.content.Context.getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String, int)' on a null object reference
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.getSharedPreferences(ContextWrapper.java:179)
        at android.preference.PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(PreferenceManager.java:526)
        at com.nicorodriguez.yarokshigherorlower.MainActivity.getSavedHighScore(MainActivity.java:32)
        at com.nicorodriguez.yarokshigherorlower.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:20)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
        at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(AppComponentFactory.java:69)
        at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(CoreComponentFactory.java:41)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1219)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3030)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3282) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1970) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7156) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:975)
```

Comment: Explore `SharedPreferences` as a simple means of storing a key-value pair.

Comment: Woah! That is cool! So, if you have the time, could you tell me how to use it? I found this on a website.                                                                                                     Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
editor.putString("key", "value");
editor.commit();                                                                                                                     Where do I put the key and value? And how to I call it? I'm sorry, I am very new to java.

Comment: @codebod Care to submit that comment as an answer?

Comment: Yes, make that an answer so I can check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following to your Activity:

```
private static final String SAVED_HIGH_SCORE_INT = "high_score";

private void saveHighScore(int highScore) {
    SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    SharedPreferences.Editor spe = sp.edit();
    spe.putInt(SAVED_HIGH_SCORE_INT, highScore);
    spe.apply();
}

private int getSavedHighScore() {
    SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    return sp.getInt(SAVED_HIGH_SCORE_INT, -1);
}
```

Call `saveHighScore(newHighScore)` whenever a game is completed.  Call `getSavedHighScore` in your button click listener's `onClick` method and use the result in your `Toast`.

Comment: Thanks again for helping me. I've got one problem. The app installs just fine, but then it crashes whenever I try to open it. I think it's because there's not a number assigned to highscore, just getSavedHighScore(). I wanted to use getSavedHighScore as highscore's initial value because otherwise, it leaves highscore as being the value that I assigned initially. How do I assign a value to getSavedHighScore without it being the same value every time I start the app? int highscore = getSavedHighScore();

Comment: `getSavedHighScore` will return `-1` when there has not previously been a saved high score. It seems unlikely that this value would cause a crash. Please post your stacktrace on crash (from Logcat) so that we can help to solve this.

Comment: The edits above are from the tab AppComponentFactory.java if you want some stacktrace from the other tabs(Instrumentation.java, CoreComponentFactory.java) please ask.

Comment: That's not the stacktrace. That's the source code for `AppComponentFactory`. If you are using Android Studio you should able to see events in Logcat. You should be able to filter on Errors and copy the stacktrace at point of crashing.

Comment: Okay, thank you for being patient. Like I said, I am a noob.

Comment: See: https://developer.android.com/studio/debug#systemLogView

Comment: I've now seen the stacktrace. Are you calling `getSavedHighScore` in `onCreate` (after `super`) or later in the Activity lifecycle? Perhaps show your Activity code.

Comment: This won't work on construction: `int highscore = getSavedHighScore();` because it is too soon in the Activity lifecycle. Just write `int highscore;`. In `onCreate()`, change `getSavedHighScore();` to `highscore = getSavedHighScore();`.

Comment: OHMYGOSHITWORKSTHANKYOUTHANKYOU! Give this person a cookie! You deserve it!